# Zend Studio and PHPCloud

Tags: zend-studio

I created from scratch a cloud app located at:
http://jimszend.my.phpcloud.com/

I have zero files on my local drive, but I am trying to get them from the server using Zend Studio.

I have found this page to accomplish this but it does not work:
http://www.phpcloud.com/help/studio-remote-system

Step 1. I believe to be correct. But I have no way to know for sure.
Step 2. Open the PHP or Zend Framework project that you want to upload to your application container, or create a new project.   <--- I want to create a new project on my hard drive.

So Step 2 somehow does not work, so instead I go to File -> New -> PHP Project from Zend Developer Cloud.

So I give the project a name: say ABC
The location is: C:\Users\Jim\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace
The container from a dropdown is: http://jimszend.my.phpcloud.com:10082 (Id: 4_0 )

Now I click refresh right below that and I get nothing so now I click on Add Target
and I enter a username and password. This dialog screen is the problem. I can't figure out what to enter here. meaning I have tried hundreds of different ways and I get stuck right here. I always end up clicking on Generate new key and then I click Test Connection and since there is no error, I assume this is correct.

Then I close that screen and now when I click on the drop down for Application nothing gets filled in. But sometimes this does work and I find my application which says, "jimszend zend framework" - something like this, but even if I get this far then I get some sort of Git failure when I click finish.

Does anyone know a full proof way to pull down "my files" using Zend Studio from PHP Cloud?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I decided to use WinSCP to get the remote files to my local machine. And then set up a sync so that anything I change locally will be sent up to phpCloud. Kind of convoluted for now. The main issue seems to be somehow I broke the private keys on my machine and don't know how to fix them for Zend Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may not have your public / private keys set or somewhere you are not supplying the correct credentials during the process.  I did the following.

Follow this help document very closely.  It's a really good doc from the phpcloud people.

http://www.phpcloud.com/help/putty-ssh-debug-tunnel

Using the phpcloud admin I created a new public / private key pair (Zend Studio kind, ending in .pem).  Then I downloaded the .pem to a folder on my windows 7 machine.

Next download from the [putty website](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) these three applications to help you match your private / public key pair in putty and in Zend Studio.  For me I wanted everything hooked up, both Putty and Zend Studio.

-PuttyGen
-Pageant
-Putty

Note putty uses a .ppk file type (not .pem), so Using PuttyGen I opened the .pem file and saved out the private key to the same location where I saved my .pem file from the php cloud.  I kept the same file naming convention, to keep matters straight.  So the only difference between the two files was .pem and .ppk.

Next I opened Pageant and used Pageant to open a store my .ppk file.  I understand Pageant to be a key store which Putty will check, as it needs to open locked doors.

Next I followed the guidelines in the above phpcloud link, carefully, to establish a tunnel.

Once the tunnel was open, I launched Zend Studio.

From there I went to Windows->preferences and searched for SSH2.  Once the SSJ2 dialog opened, under the general tab I added both my .pem and .ppk to the path.  Then under the Key Management tab dialog I used "Load existing key" and loaded my .pem file.  Then I clicked apply.

Then using Zend Studio I created a new "PHP Project from Remote Server".  I went though the steps clicking "Manage remote servers".  For the server connection I typed the follow.

JAZZFINGERS.MY.PHPCLOUD.COM

and if you are prompted for credentials, do not use the container credentials, unless they are the same as your other credentials.

From there you can also test your connection.  For me this worked.  Hope this helps.  Oh yeah, also read this.  Very important and helpful.

www.phpcloud.com/help/studio-remote-system

-Best Wishes